# Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ and little O notation

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Here, $x$ is a fixed number, and $n$ goes to infinity.

I want to prove that $(1+ \frac{x+\frac{1}{2}\log 4\pi - \frac{1}{2} \log \log n}{\log n} + o(\frac{1}{\log n}))^{\frac{1}{2}} = 1+\frac{x-\frac{1}{2} \log 4\pi - \frac{1}{2} \log \log n}{2\log n} + o(\frac{1}{\log n})$.

I know that $\sqrt{1+x} = 1+\frac{x}{2} + o(x)$, but plugging in, I get

$1+\frac{x-\frac{1}{2} \log 4\pi - \frac{1}{2} \log \log n}{2 \log n} + o(\frac{1}{\log n}) + o( \frac{x-\frac{1}{2} \log 4\pi - \frac{1}{2} \log \log n}{2\log n} + o(\frac{1}{\log n}))) = 1+\frac{x-\frac{1}{2} \log 4\pi - \frac{1}{2} \log \log n}{2\log n} + o(\frac{1}{\log n}) + o(\frac{\log \log n}{\log n}) = 1+\frac{x-\frac{1}{2} \log 4\pi - \frac{1}{2} \log \log n}{2\log n} + o(\frac{\log \log n}{\log n})$

What did I do wrong? This is in little-o notation.

Thank you.

Here is the relevant section:
[image]

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#31696): **Pare question to its basics**. In this case, for example, since $x$ is fixed you could replace $x+\tfrac{1}{2}\log 4\pi$ by $C$.